# ListView in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am getting following error when I use pagination of view.

> Unable to render the data. If the problem persists, contact your web
>   server administrator.
> Correlation
>   ID:c64a4e9d-64d2-3009-f658-7f1c8b0faebc

When I checked the Logs from ULSViewer I got these errors messages

> Error while executing web part: System.ArgumentException: The
>   specified view is invalid.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.get_Item(Guid guid)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.InplaceViewEditor.get_View()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.InplaceViewEditor.RenderListView()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.InplaceViewEditor.Execute(String
>   strCmd)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.InplaceViewEditor.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)
>
> Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 12/24/2015 10:59:32.88, Original
>   Level: Verbose] No data was found on the incoming client request
>   Proxy response returned error: 'The remote server returned an error:
>   (601).'

Could you please check and let me know what is the issue? I am not able to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Manoj.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the custom web parts or add custom code?

For troubleshooting the issue, you could check things below:

1. Create a new list view to check if the same issue will occur.
2. Do an IIS reset to check if it can work.

Comment: Hello Amy, Thanks for your answer, This is OOTB view created using the list. I have created new list view and its working fine with all its features. Tried with IIS reset however, this old listview gave same issue.